# working directory in nested projects

Tags: python, autotools, waf

I have a background in autotools and I am used to make use of `top_srcdir`, `top_builddir`, `srcdir` and `builddir`.

When I have nested projects, the working directory will change to the one where I define my `Makefile.am` in the project.

However, in waf, I am converting a project that has two subprojects inside:

- Static library.
- Program.

With this structure:

- root/wscript (this recurses into subprojects).
- root/myprogram/wscript
- root/mylib/wscript

When I put these together in a superproject, I see that now, the working directory, no matter which wscript is executed, is always `root/`. The equivalent with a `Makefile.am` in the same places would change the working directory when recursing.

1. What is the best way to get the "typical" behaviour from autotools? I mean making use of `builddir`, `srcdir` etc.
2. What are the best practices in waf regarding to this problem? Is it done in another novel way I don't know of?